# Cross reference is not working in the interactive table (DT) in bookdown

Tags: r, bookdown

The cross reference works as expected in the text and `knitr::kable`, but doesn't convert into links in the interactive table (DT package) for the `gitbook`.

I create a minimum example to show my question. This link is the source: https://github.com/byzheng/bookdown-test and this link is the deployed website: https://engineer-jocelyn-50227.netlify.com/

Basically, I created a figure with chunk name `test-figure`, and created a table using function `DT::datatable`.

```
DT::datatable(data.frame(Figure = "Figure \\@ref(fig:test-figure)"))
```

bookdown doesn't convert into link.

[image]

Comment: This won't work. The table is generated by JS and not processed by bookdown.

Comment: Thanks @YihuiXie. Is it possible to add this feature in bookdown/DT?. I am using bookdown to write a software doc and have automatically generated a cross reference table to link all figures/tables in my doc. I would like to use DT to filter and search column as the table is tool long. Can see an example here: https://apsim-wheat-doc.bangyou.me/output.html